# Flagging a question for migration

Tags: discussion

See the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429942/need-a-batchfile-to-run-on-startup-shutdown-logon-logoff-lock-unlock-for-a-wi). I didn't think the question was outright off-topic on stackoverflow so I didn't vote to close, but I felt it would probably be more appropriate on superuser and get a better response there. When the OP agreed and asked how to do that, I flagged it for him with this explanation:

> OP wants the question moved to superuser. Probably better off there.

Well, I got my answer from a moderator:

> declined - Super User is part of the standard migration path; use
>   that instead of flagging for moderator attention.

Yes, I know it's part of the standard migration path, and I would have voted to close with that reason if I had felt it was off topic -- *but I didn't*, as my comments made clear. I thought the more helpful thing to do for the OP would be to flag it and let a mod take care of it. Besides, a vote to close probably would have just left it in the review queue indefinitely and accomplished nothing.

Interestingly, I've flagged similar questions in the past with this exact same comment and had them marked helpful.

So now the question will sit there and rot, a new user gets no assistance,  and I'm left with a decidedly negative experience.

Is it really so hard to migrate a question that it was worth telling me to go pound sand instead of just doing it?

Is there a better way to handle this or should I just let newbs fend for themselves in the future?

Comment: I think the moderator's comment was somewhat unhelpful.

Comment: Ugh.  Batch scripting questions are barely *barely* on topic.  But this isn't even a batch script--he's asking how to use a command line program to perform a specific type of shutdown, and how to use features of the operating system to execute it in certain situations. That's completely off topic.

Comment: You do know there are do different close reasons for SU right?  `close -> off topic-> SU` just closes the Q and points the user to SU.  `close -> off topic -> belongs on another site -> SU` will actually move the Q to SU.  No need to mod flag when it is something we can do ourselves.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I know what the options are. No, non-moderators can't move anything. They can only vote and it requires 4 more votes to accomplish. I discussed this in my question.

Comment: Couldn't have the asker requested the migration instead? I don't understand why somebody else has to do it for him. It's his question so he should take care of it and create an account in the target site, initiate the migration, etc.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, the user could have requested it himself. He's new. I was merely trying to be helpful by doing it for him and then explaining how to do it himself in the future. What's silly here is that a user can't migrate his own question and has to ask a mod to do it for them.

Comment: @CareyGregory I agree. There should be a simple path to migrate your own question without need of any third party if the question hasn't yet got answers. Maybe that could be a feature request.

Comment: @CareyGregory If your issue is with the number of people required and the fact that it might not get enough exposure you can always hop into the [SOCVR chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and see what they think.  If people agree with you then they may vote as well which could speed up the process.

Comment: @Ed Bayiates: How would you have responded?

Comment: @boltclock, it's not that easy to find "standard migration path" and I didn't know what it was when I read this question.  NathanOliver posted a comment at 13:36 above that is much clearer than the moderator's comment.

Answer (score 21):

I think the point (that could have been made more clearly) is that moderators should only need to intervene or action something where the community cannot do this themselves.

So the question may not be enitrely off-topic, but *there is* a way to migrate the question without moderator intervention. It's an exception - but an exception that can be, and should be, handled by the community without adding to the workload for moderators.

In this kind of scenario - VTC and use the standard migration path. If you fear the OP may have a bad experience, drop a comment on the post explaining *why* you've close voted.

Comment: "VTC and use the standard migration path." I would say it still gives the wrong impression as there is nothing wrong with this question (as long as it is on-topic) and it might be the standard migration path doesn't get enough votes. I feel the standard migration path is only for Qs which are off-topic here. Maybe there is some feature missing.

Comment: @Trilarion it may indeed give the wrong impression which is why I mentioned leaving a comment to explain _why_ the close vote has been used. It may be that there is a gap somewhere, but in my personal opinion a feature should be there to make things easier for the majority, and I would class this as an exception.

Comment: Okay. I still prefer the solution by [Lundin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320606/1536976) and would rather recommend Cut&Paste of the asker instead of five close votes on behalf of him.

Comment: Which is equally as valid, because it doesn't require moderator intervention which is what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 15):

> I know it's part of the standard migration path, and I would have voted to close with that reason if I had felt it was off topic -- but I didn't, as my comments made clear.

Ok, so do nothing. Make your case in the comments for why it should stay on Stack Overflow

> I thought the more helpful thing to do for the OP would be to flag it and let a mod take care of it.

It's a great thought; but one of the reasons we have a lot of flags in the queue that shouldn't be there is because people deferred things to moderators that the community can handle themselves.

That's also why your flag was declined. We actively work to empower the community to handle things themselves; and if we see a flag that goes asks a moderator to do something within the power of the community, we're going to decline it.

The problem isn't the flag, or the next flag, it's when that effect snowballs and causes the moderator workload to increase again and again for requests that aren't necessary for a moderator to handle.

> Besides, a vote to close probably would have just left it in the review queue indefinitely and accomplished nothing.

That's a different problem to solve; and solving it by asking moderators to step in only makes both situations worse.

Comment: If flags like this create an unacceptable workload for moderators then that's a much bigger problem they need to address. Telling users to put questions in the review queue where they'll most likely languish until they become useless to the OP isn't much of a solution to that or any other problem. What would solve this problem immediately would be allowing users to migrate their own questions. Why they can't is a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: @CareyGregory This is how we address that "much bigger problem" by declining flags that should be handled by the community.

Comment: That's not a very effective or user friendly solution. Requiring 5 votes to migrate something the OP *wants* migrated is overly bureaucratic and a waste of a whole lot of people's time. And if you want that to be the policy, you're going to need to consult the other mods who apparently don't agree.

Comment: @CareyGregory If the OP wants it moved so bad and it doesn't have an answer yet, they can delete it and post it to the correct site. (If they're new, and you say this one was (I didn't look), they're more likely to just post the question to the other site and leave the one on the first site sit undeleted.) Are you sure the OP didn't _already_ do that?

Comment: @Kendra Yep, they sure can. I'll be sure not to try and assist new users in the future lest I annoy a mod. </snark>

Comment: @CareyGregory Another way to fix this particular problem is to go support and make noise on this feature request: [Should we allow self-migration of questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22051/should-we-allow-self-migration-of-questions).

Answer (score -5):

You could have done it better. When you vote to migrate, you see the following options, which include superuser:

[image]

Now I'll give you an example. If there is an answer, which is Spam. Now let's say two users do two different things:

- **First User:** Flags it as Spam.
- **Second User:** Flags it as a custom flag, and writes in it: "This is spam. Delete it".

You know what must have happened. The first users flag get marked helpful, the second users flag is marked as declined. The post is deleted.

In another case, where there is no "User One". The second user does the same thing. The flag will get declined, but if the post is spam, it will get deleted. This is because, a spam post should be deleted. But one does not need to waste a moderator's time in doing this, when there is an option for spam. Thus it got declined, to teach the second user a lesson.

Now you apply the same example in your case. There was an option for you to migrate to Superuser. But you didn't take that option. You took the foolish decision of custom flagging as the second user (above example of spam post) did. So what do you expect? The flag to be approved? Of course not.

> Besides, a vote to close probably would have just left it in the review queue indefinitely and accomplished nothing.

I agree with your point. But then it's the process. There are lots of questions being voted every day to be migrated. Is your question much more special from the others? No. It is just another question. I understand your thought, but you have to follow the process. If you think of something else, like custom flagging, or introducing a new system, post a meta question, asking for whatever new system to be introduced. Till then, custom flagging is not the process.

Also, thinking that each and every question which is going to be migrated is custom flagged, there will be hundreds of more flags moderators have to review. Even when it should not happen that way.

> Interestingly, I've flagged similar questions in the past with this exact same comment and had them marked helpful.

Now can you provide the exact post you've flagged, and where they've been migrated to. Till then its difficult to say. Still I'll have a guess.

The questions you've voted to migrate must've been migrated to sites other than mentioned in the "Migration List" (Image shows what communities you can migrate using the "off-topic" option. That is appropriate. If a site you have to migrate to is not there in the list, you have to custom flag.

> Is it really so hard to migrate a question that it was worth telling me to go pound sand instead of just doing it?

The moderator must have seen the question you flagged, but did not migrate it as he / she thought that question shouldn't have been migrated. This is even on-topic on SO, and thus there is no problem if it hasn't been migrated. Plus, it is more probable for this question to get an answer on SO than Super User, because Many programmers on SO use Unix / Linux.

> Is there a better way to handle this or should I just let newbs fend for themselves in the future?

Yes. You shouldn't have custom flagged this as Super User is already there in the migration list.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score -7):

If the question is off-topic, is should be closed.

If the question is not off-topic, it should not be closed.

If the OP wants to move their on-topic question to a different site, what's stopping them? They don't need other users or moderators for this. Just post a new question on the other site. There is this thing on every modern OS called copy/paste.

Comment: Except posting duplicate questions across sites is looked down upon.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @Rob, they could delete the original question. Copy/Paste/Delete

Comment: @Rob They would delete the question. This scenario is a case where the OP themselves wants the question moved. Why do they express a need to have it moved if they won't wish to have the post deleted on the first site after the move? Otherwise they wouldn't have raised the topic to begin with, but just cross-posted it.

Comment: I really like this solution. It seems to be by far the fastest and least effort solution. I will recommend it as long as the question hasn't any answer yet. Something along the lines "You could hope for enough votes to migrate, or even easier is just to ...".